# JQuery hide/show from textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, togglebutton

I'm trying to get a password field to be shown/hidden depending on value that of a different input element.

For example if the username is "admin" it should hide the password field.

If you they type in anything else then the password field appears or remains.

```js
function togglePassword() {
  if ($("#j_username").val() == "admin")
    $("#j_password").hide();
}
```

```html
<label>User Name</label>
<input type='text' id="j_username" name='j_username' style='text-align: Left;' MaxLength='100' size='20' tabindex='1' onkeypress='javascript:return loginIdKeyPress(event);' />

<label>Password</label>
<input type='password' id="j_password" name='j_password' value='' Align='Left' size='20' tabindex='2' onkeypress='javascript:return passwordKeyPress(event);' />
<br/>
```

Currently this code doesn't work for me, what should I change?

Comment: so what is the question ?

Comment: @Ankur how do i toggle password field when the user types in admin. The code above isnt working the password field still is there

Comment: onkeypress=togglePassword should do

Comment: @Ankur nope it doesnt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add jQuery library and do like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#j_username').on('input',function(){
    if($(this).val() =='admin'){
      $('#j_password').hide();
    }else{
      $('#j_password').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>User Name</label>
     <input type='text' id="j_username" name='j_username' style='text-align: Left;' MaxLength='100' size='20' tabindex='1'/>
       <br/>    
<label>Password</label>
<input type='password' id="j_password" name='j_password' value='' Align='Left' size='20' tabindex='2'/>
<br/>
```

Note:- You use `$` syntax which is jQuery syntax actually.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event along with the [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to toggle hide/show.

Example below outputs the value of the condition on each keypress to the console. If admin string is present, password field is hidden.

```js
$("#j_username").on("keyup", function() {
  //gets value of input element and evaluates if true/false
  var inputValue = ($(this).val() == "admin");
  //outputs value in console for each keypress
  console.log(inputValue);
  //shows password field if inputValue is false, hides if true
  $("#j_password").toggle( !inputValue );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>User Name</label>
<input type='text' id="j_username" name='j_username' style='text-align: Left;' MaxLength='100' size='20' tabindex='1'  />
<br/>
<label>Password</label>
<input type='password' id="j_password" name='j_password' value='' Align='Left' size='20' tabindex='2'/>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code where ensure the case sensitivity :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#j_username').on('input',function(){
    if($(this).val().toLowerCase().trim() === 'admin'){
      $("#j_password").hide();
    }
    else {
      $("#j_password").show();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should actually call your function `togglePassword()`

Second, you need to call it when you release a key, i.e. you need to use `onkeyup`. Otherwise your password field will update one keystroke "too late" because `onkeypress` calls the function when the key is pushed down, i.e. when you press "n" it will be called, before the n actually is written.

And last, you should also include an else-clause, to show your `input` in case it is hidden and the username is changed to something else.

```js
function togglePassword() {
  if ($("#j_username").val() == "admin") {
    $("#j_password").hide();
  } else {
    $("#j_password").show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>User Name</label>
<input type='text' id="j_username" name='j_username' style='text-align: Left;' MaxLength='100' size='20' tabindex='1' onkeyup='javascript:togglePassword();' />

<label>Password</label>
<input type='password' id="j_password" name='j_password' value='' Align='Left' size='20' tabindex='2' />
<br/>
```